# Post Request with special Characters in XML String

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I write below code to post request in soap webservices:

```
NSString *newstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@/Enki_UpperWs.asmx",[WebServices RequestURL]];
NSString *soapMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<Generate_Facility_List xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<UserID>%d</UserID>\n"
                         "<LicenseKey>%d</LicenseKey>\n"
                         "<token>%@</token>\n"
                         "</Generate_Facility_List>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>",UserId,OfficeKey,strUserToken];

    soapMsg=[self getcodeforkeys:soapMsg];

    NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [soapMsg length]];
    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[newstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *myRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:myURL cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed timeoutInterval:500];
    [myRequest setValue:@"text/xml; charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-type"];
    [myRequest addValue:@"http://tempuri.org/Generate_Facility_List" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [myRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [myRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [myRequest setHTTPBody:[soapMsg dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:myRequest delegate:self];
    self.connection = con;
    [con release];
    [myURL release];
    [newstr release];
    [soapMsg release];
    return [self doParsing];
```

But If any parameter having special character like < Or > Or & or ' or " and if I replace it  with using below function:

```
-(NSString*)getcodeforkeys:(NSString*)str_code{
    str_code = [str_code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&" withString:@"&amp;"];
    str_code = [str_code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@"&lt;"];
    str_code = [str_code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@"&gt;"];
    str_code = [str_code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"'" withString:@"&apos;"];
    str_code = [str_code stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"&quot;"];
    return str_code;
}
```

It replace the XML characters as well..due to which i am not able to post request in XML format. I just need to replace the objects that passed and keep remain XML format as it is but How???

For example if I pass strUserToken as @"testing<&>" then it will replace its special characters but not XML string.

Can Anyone help??

Answer (score 1):

[XML Validation](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_dtd.asp):

> XML validated against a DTD is "Valid" XML.

You might want to try one of this approaches to make sure the final XML is valid:

1. Use [CDATA](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp) section for the text content.
2. Escape the text content separately (that is `UserId`,`OfficeKey`,`strUserToken` in your case).

---

1.

```
NSString *soapMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<Generate_Facility_List xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<UserID><![CDATA[%d]]></UserID>\n"
                         "<LicenseKey><![CDATA[%d]]></LicenseKey>\n"
                         "<token><![CDATA[%@]]></token>\n"
                         "</Generate_Facility_List>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>",UserId,OfficeKey,strUserToken]; // the text inside CDATA is not parsed as a part of XML, it might have special characters unescaped. The parser should support CDATA though

// do not escape complete document - remove the line soapMsg=[self getcodeforkeys:soapMsg];
```

2.

```
NSString *soapMsg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                         "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                         "<soap:Body>\n"
                         "<Generate_Facility_List xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">\n"
                         "<UserID>%d</UserID>\n"
                         "<LicenseKey>%d</LicenseKey>\n"
                         "<token>%@</token>\n"
                         "</Generate_Facility_List>\n"
                         "</soap:Body>\n"
                         "</soap:Envelope>",
                         [self getcodeforkeys:UserId],
                         [self getcodeforkeys:OfficeKey],
                         [self getcodeforkeys:strUserToken]]; // escape text separately

// do not escape complete document - remove the line soapMsg=[self getcodeforkeys:soapMsg];
```

Comment: But How can I use CDATA in objective C?? Can u please give me some example?? Is there any class to import??

Comment: @Divya Jain that's not objective-c type but part of XML documents format, you use it as text inside XML documents and any decent parser must handle it correctly (i.e. parsing the text inside `<![CDATA[%@]]>` as text with any characters). There're two examples at the answer as well as the link to definition of valid XML document and  description of CDATA element.